# Make a custom search bar in glossary in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

There is an error says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToSelect() on null

```
<?php
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('btn-save')) {
    $search = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $searchKey = '';
  if($search) {
      $searchKey = $search['gsearch'];
  }

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('glossary/word_collection');
  $words ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
  $words ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('name' => $searchKey, 'eq' => true)));
  echo $words->getSelect();
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: i made an custom search bar in glossary but there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('btn-save')) {
    $search = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $searchKey = '';
  if(isset($search['gsearch'])) {
      $searchKey = $search['gsearch'];
  }

    $words = Mage::getResourceModel('glossary/word_collection');
    $words->addFieldToFilter("name", array("eq" => $searchKey)));
    echo $words->getSelect();
}
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('btn-save')) {
    $search = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $searchKey = '';
  if(isset($search['gsearch'])) {
      $searchKey = $search['gsearch'];
  }

    $words = Mage::getResourceModel('glossary/word_collection');
    $words->addFieldToFilter("name", array("like" => $searchKey)));
    echo $words->getSelect();
}
?>
```

Comment: welcome back :)

Comment: how do i output that if search this data this data i want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Use addFieldToSelect incase of addAttributeToSelect

addFieldToSelect used for flat model

addAttributeToSelect user for EAV model

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand you want below code change as I mentioned

```
<?php
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost('btn-save')) {
$search = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$searchKey = '';
 if($search) {
  $searchKey = $search['gsearch'];
 }

 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('glossary/word_collection');
 $collection ->addFieldToSelect('name');
 $collection ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('name' => $searchKey, 'eq' => true)));
 echo $collection->getSelect();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used variable is `$words`

that should be `$collection`

your code look like below:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('glossary/word_collection');
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('name' => $searchKey, 'eq' => true)));
  echo $collection->getSelect();
```